# How to make dash search outside the home folder

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I am new to Ubuntu and very excited about life outside the MS-bubble! ;-)

I want to set up a computer which shall serve as a library.

My system partition is on a SSD. The data (pdf, mp4, mp3 files) will be on a separate HDD. I as administrator will be the only one to write to the HDD. The other users of this computer need to search through the data on the HDD and read it.

Now here is my question:
How can I make the dash search/index the content of the HDD so everyone can easily search through it? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Unity already searches the entire system for files or information, as long as the **user has permission to read it** and **the drive the information is on is mounted**.

I tested this with my internal "Storage" HDD, searched something in it, and it found it (albeit after a few seconds).

You need to make sure the guest user (or kiosk user, or whatever user is searching things) has **read** and possibly **execute** permissions, but not **write** permissions. You can ensure this by going to the folder **above** where your data is stored and run the command (assuming your data folder is named "Data" and your username is `MYADMINUSERNAME`):

```
chown MYADMINUSERNAME:MYADMINUSERNAME Data -R
chmod 755 Data -R
```

This will set the owner and group of the folder `Data` to your user, then give you full permission (**7**55), your group read and execute permission (7**5**5), and anybody else read and execute permission (75**5**).

After that, Unity will find your data, just it might take a while on a standard HDD. There's a lot of kiosk user mode settings you can do to optimize the search and the kiosk user experience, but that's for another post / question.